# Modding questions by high rep users, is discouraging, unjust, unfair and needs to be revised

Tags: discussion

By searching deeply through SOF, you may notice there're ridiculous, funny questions which are not modded, downgraded, closed, hold or whatever. Also you can see several good questions (If not good, at least they're not so basic or so funny!) which have gone under unfair moderation actions.

Moderation is a basic requirement in virtual places like this but there should be a unique standard for it. High Reps are humans and it's natural for them to have different tastes. Different taste means different styles of thinking and judging and this is when injustice happens.

Comment: Have you also compared the age between the questions? This site has become more and more strict as the quantity of questions has increased.

Comment: Exactly. This site has, what, seven million questions now?

Comment: over 9 million @Pekka웃

Comment: Do you have any examples of high rep users doing something unfair?

Comment: Oh boy, here we go again. Links, or it didn't happen. Plus, you haven't made any real suggestions yet.

Comment: Wait, we're modding questions now? Who's working on Team Fortress Classic for this thing?

Comment: LOL! After asking this question here on meta, I can see the heat is increased on editing my questions on that other side of SOF! Even it says I've lost some few reps! Now it IS funny!

Comment: 1 downvote vs. a user helping you out by improving several posts. I'd say that's a net positive.

Comment: Yes, no problem. When I run into a profile that can use some help I'm happy to assist.

Comment: :^)))))) You know ... I was wondering ... Why did you put this one on hold?!  I mean, Is it hard for high-reps not to downgrade something?

Comment: I voted to close this question for the given reason, you state that you believe there is a problem, give no real evidence, and make no suggestions for correcting it. Thats not really an answerable (or even discussable) question, especially given how many complaints like this are *already* on Meta.

Comment: ^ that. Same here.

Comment: @Bradley: Put my question away and let's stick to this: "especially given how many complaints like this are already on Meta" so haven't you asked yourself (selves) why there are MANY COMPLAINTS?

Comment: Sure, but the answer is pretty simple (usually). People don't like being told their content isn't up to par, and even if only 0.01% of those people take their complaint to meta, we get **so many bad questions** that it still shows up *a lot*.

Comment: Each and every time. Read through them. If you have something new to bring to the table, do so.

Comment: This within a day of a 500k rep user getting suspended for destroying content.  No, SO doesn't play favorites for high rep users, other than trying not to drive them away with shit questions.

Comment: @High-Reps: Thanks I got my answer (Although, you believe I didn't actually ask a question!)

Comment: @Vynylyn yes there are complaints. With the amount of people frequenting the site, it's to be expected. Although the fact that everytime someone comes in with such a complaint, the community always pushes back saying "no".... shows something as well. In any case, for YOUR question, you're just ranting. Propose a solution, link proofs of what you say... SOMETHING

Comment: Why this was put [on hold]? We can still discuss it (and being helpful for future research) as it was tagged actually. Give an appropriate duplicate please, or don't close this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In my view, there isn't anything to discuss here. If you feel there is an actual discussable topic/question among the rant, please edit it and I will be more than happy to consider casting a reopen vote.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm not so sure that the OP is simply _a rant_. It's asking why the site is behaving like this, and shows inconsistent handling of questions and answers. So answers are valuable for it I'd say this will be useful for future researchers on that topic (no matter if that quesiton is downvoted here or not).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I could see that with the bottom paragraph removed, the last bit of the top paragraph modified so that its not assuming the actions were unfair (which is unsubstantiated so far anyways) and then some linked examples. I totally get what you are saying, but if we need a canonical "why do we treat some questions differently" question, I would just make one thats better formed than this. Like I said, feel free to try and edit this one into shape though.

Answer (score 3):

> High Reps are humans and it's natural for them to have different tastes. Different taste means different styles of thinking and judging

This is 100% correct.  It's the reason why the vast majority of moderation actions (most notably closure (usually) and deletion) are actions that non-moderators cannot make unilaterally.  It requires 3-5 users to agree to take the action in question for it to happen.  Additionally, virtually all moderation actions are reversible, allowing the community to correct actions that are found to have been inappropriate (or that have since been fixed).

These major decision decisions mean that the state of any one question isn't just decided on by a single person, but rather by something resembling community consensus.

Answer (score 2):

> *"you may notice there're ridiculous, funny questions which are not modded, downgraded, closed, hold or whatever"*

The site's policies have evolved over time. There's a number of *old* questions and answers that are even accepted against these, by their

- historical impact (and generally improved helpfulness)
- wiki adopted state
- undergoing *"the radar"*

Life isn't fair that way, but the [current rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) are in action for newly asked questions.

> *"High Reps are humans and it's natural for them to have different tastes. Different taste means different styles of thinking and judging and this is when injustice happens."*

Of course we are humans (robots don't work well on this side so far and AFAIK), but it's still we have to agree the *current rules* as stated above.

If you think that there was a failed judgement about these, you can flag your question or answer for moderator attention to clarify.
But I'd only recommend this as a **very last resort**!

Most of the time 5 agreed users (3 for deletion), a single trusted user (applying a duplicate for a specific tag), or an elected site-moderator are right with their judgement.

You can ask for support posting a link to your question/answer
 on Meta SO. But I'd also discourage this, because it could just *strike back* due to the [**Meta Effect**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: And when all else fails, you *can* take the question to meta to get more community input. This often generates a negative Meta Effect when you are wrong (which happens way more often than not), so do so at your own risk.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Good point actually (_"Meta Effect"_)!